# Multiple UPDATE from SELECT with multiple rows in WHERE clause [Mysql]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.parameterA = 1
  WHERE Table1.parameterB = ? 
  AND Table1.parameterC = (
    SELECT Table2.id 
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE Table2.parameterD = ? AND Table2.date > ?
  )
```

This is not working because the select is returning multiple rows:

```
{ Error: ER_SUBQUERY_NO_1_ROW: Subquery returns more than 1 row }
```

Is it possible a workaround to do this multiple update?

Comment: try changing `AND Table1.parameterC = (` to `AND Table1.parameterC IN (`

Comment: if you are using '=' your subquery must return just 1 row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using `=` SQL expects a single value.

if you want to work with a list of results - you should use [`IN`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php) like this:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.parameterA = 1
   WHERE Table1.parameterB = ? 
   AND Table1.parameterC IN (
     SELECT Table2.id 
       FROM Table2 
       WHERE Table2.parameterD = ? AND Table2.date > ?
   )
```